# Incomplete file copy from NodeJS to Amazon S3 with

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-s3

For reliability reasons I'm transferring some images from an external source to a Amazon S3 storage.

However, the images are truncated and looks like in the image below.
The code I use has the following logic:

```
const request = require('request');
let r = request(pictureUrl);
r.on('response', function(rs){
  let newFileName = new Date().getTime() + '_' + externalId+'.jpg';
  let localPath = __dirname+'/../../temp_files/'+newFileName+'';
  let ws = fs.createWriteStream(localPath);
  rs.pipe(ws);
  rs.on('end', function(){
    fs.readFile(localPath, (error, fileContent) => {
      uploadToS3(fileContent, newFileName, 'profile_pics', function (err, response) {
        fs.unlink(localPath, (err) => {

           /* send response to browser */
```

What I believe to the cause for this is one of the following:
1.   `r.on('response'`  <- the file is not received yet and the next processes start.
2. `rs.on('end'` <- the file is not written locally yet and the next processes start.
3. `fs.unlink(localPath` <- is executed before `uploadToS3(fileContent` is completed.

### Opinions?

[image: 'Incomplete image copy']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should upload your file to S3 in the callback for the [finish](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_finish) event of the writeable stream.

```
ws.on('finish', function(){
    fs.readFile(localPath, (error, fileContent) => {
      uploadToS3(fileContent, newFileName, 'profile_pics', function (err, response) {
...
```

You are correct regarding assumption #2

> 2. rs.on('end' <- the file is not written locally yet and the next processes start.

The other assumptions are wrong.

> 1. r.on('response' <- the file is not received yet and the next processes start.

#1 does not matter. Multiple  callbacks should be able to run in parallel.

> 3. fs.unlink(localPath <- is executed before uploadToS3(fileContent is completed.

#3 is probably wrong. I am not sure what `uploadToS3` does, but probably it calls the callback when the upload is completed, so the file is `unlinked` after that